# Delete duplicate rows in two columns simultaneously

Tags: r, duplicates, subset

I would like to delete duplicate rows based in two collumns, instead just one.

My input `df`:

```
RAW.PVAL  GR     allrl  Bak
0.05      fr     EN1    B12
0.05      fg     EN1    B11
0.45      fr     EN2    B10
0.35      fg     EN2    B066
```

My output:

```
RAW.PVAL  GR  allrl   Bak
0.05      fr   EN1    B12
0.45      fg   EN2    B10
0.35      fg   EN2    B066
```

I had tried `df<- subset(df, !duplicated(allrl, RAW.PVAL))`, but I do not work to delete rows with this two columns simultaneously duplicated.

Thank you!

Comment: If the targeted collumns are not subsequent, it will works?

Comment: @user3091668.  Now, your result is based on which columns that are duplicated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use `subset`, you could try:

```
  subset(df, !duplicated(subset(df, select=c(allrl, RAW.PVAL))))
 # RAW.PVAL GR allrl  Bak
 #1     0.05 fr   EN1  B12
 #3     0.45 fr   EN2  B10
 #4     0.35 fg   EN2 B066
```

But, I think @thelatemail's approach would be better

```
  df[!duplicated(df[c("RAW.PVAL","allrl")]),]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about to cite that I have another collumns. I fixed it.

Comment: @user3091668.  Looks like your columns are getting increased by every second :=)

Comment: My first example was pretty bad. I tried to make it simple, but i simplified a lot... Now I think is ok. Sorry abot that.

Answer (score -2):

Use `unique()` to remove the duplicate values.